# Select element A or element B with CSS selector

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, sizzle

Is there a way to select either one of the 2 elements specified in CSS selector expression? If element A is not found then select element B.

Example:

```
css=input[id$=sometext]@id OR textarea[id$=sometext]@id
```

The above expression should return `id` of either `input` element or `textarea` element whose `id` ends with "sometext".

As a side note, I'm trying to use this CSS selector in selenium2library which uses [sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation) for handling css selectors.

I tried the following approaches, none of them seem to work (syntax error):

```
css=input[id$=sometext]@id / textarea[id$=sometext]@id
css=input[id$=sometext]@id/textarea[id$=sometext]@id
css=input[id$=sometext]@id/css=textarea[id$=sometext]@id
css=input[id$=sometext]@id OR css=textarea[id$=sometext]@id
css=input|textarea[id$=sometext]@id
css=input[id$=sometext]@id, textarea[id$=sometext]@id
css=input[id$=sometext]@id,textarea[id$=sometext]@id
```

Comment: How about using if else Java or any programming language??

Comment: @Maitreya Yes, I could handle it in Python or Java but I was wondering if there is a pure CSS solution to this.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. It will break the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Sizzle uses CSS selectors, and, for example, `@id` is not a CSS selector. I'm personally not sure what `@id` is supposed to mean, but, without that part, try:

```
input[id$=sometext],textarea[id$=sometext]
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment but I tried this already, see the last one of my attempts in the original question. `@id` is just a way that Robot Framework extracts the value of the `id` attribute from the identified element.